# How to kill the last opened Internet Explorer window using a command?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, command-line

I'm trying to write a Windows command file to open a webpage in IE, wait for it to load, then close the IE window. The following works but will kill all IE windows so any that were already open before running the .cmd will also get closed.

```
start iexplore.exe "page to load"
ping localhost -n 10 > nul
taskkill /IM iexplore.exe
```

I only want to kill the IE that was opened. I know I can just kill a particular process if I know its PID but how can find this from the command line? Is there a way to get it when starting the IE window? What I really want to do is:

```
start iexplore.exe "page to load"
ping localhost -n 10 > nul
taskkill /PID ?
```

where ? is the PID of the IE that gets opened but how can I get this? This needs to run as a .cmd file without any input from a user.

Comment: Maybe grab a tool like Process Explorer, http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessExplorer.zip . I think what you need to do is only kill the iexplore.exe with the highest process ID. My two cents.

Comment: Its going to be run on various machines so I don't wont to have to install something on all of them and its going to be a scheduled job so can't rely on  a user checking what the highest is, I need to be able to do it as part of a command if possible.

Comment: Last time I checked, killing one iexplore.exe process crashes them all.

Comment: Not if you do `taskkill /PID X` where X is the PID of the one you want to kill, I just can't figure out how to get it on the command line.

Comment: Will you be able to determine the last IE window from
 it's title?

Comment: Which version of IE?  IE6, 7, and 8 are all different in how processes correspond to windows.  IE6 is one process per window (generally speaking, there are exceptions).  IE7 can have one process per window, plus a shared process (ieuser.exe).  IE8 can have one process per tab, plus an extra process.

Comment: @nick I know what the title will be as I know what page the script will load. How does that help with closing the correct one from a script?

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy I think its IE7 but will check.

Comment: the /fi switch of taskkill can be used to kill things by windowtitle. (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)
so something like taskkill /fi "Windowtitle eq My Awesome page - Windows Internet Explorer" should work. The accepted answer is probably better since the multiprocess-ness of IE7-8 could cause some trickiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE already supports automation, there is no point in finding and killing the correct process:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.visible=true
IE.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/"
while IE.Busy
 WScript.Sleep 555
 wend
IE.Quit
```

Save as .vbs (And run with wscript.exe from parent program/batch file)

Comment: Cheers. Does what I want and can control the time exactly (it was bit rough with my ping example).

Answer (score 0):

use vbscript

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strProcess = objArgs(0) 'argument, which is the process name
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
' call WMI service Win32_Process 
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '"&strProcess&"'")
t=0
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    ' do some fine tuning on the process creation date to get rid of "." and "+"
    s = Replace( objProcess.CreationDate ,".","")
    s = Replace( objProcess.CreationDate ,"+","")
    ' Find the greatest value of creation date
    If s > t Then
        t=s
        strLatestPid = objProcess.ProcessID
    End If    
Next
WScript.Echo "latest: " & t , strLatestPid
'Call WMI to terminate the process using the found process id above
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where ProcessId =" & strLatestPid)
For Each objProcess in colProcess
    objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

usage:

```
c:\test>cscript //nologo kill.vbs "iexplore.exe"
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of an explanation for how that works please? I've not used vbscript before.