# Kill started Internet Explorer process without closing all IE browsers

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-10, kill-process

My C# program uses Selenium IE web driver to open a websites to do the automated testing (multiple browsers can be open if the websites could not be reached in the first attempt). After doing all the tests, the program will kill started IE processes, but the problem is that it also closes all IE browser that were not opened by the program (like in the case the user opened other websites in IE before running the program.) How could I fix this problem. This is my code:

```
 public void KillAllBrowsersAndWebDrivers()
    {
        var webDrivers = Process.GetProcessesByName("IEDriverServer").Select(p => p.Id);
        var browsers = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore").Select(p => p.Id);
        var processIds = webDrivers.Concat(browsers);
        foreach (var pid in processIds)
        {              
                Process.GetProcessById(pid).Kill();                    
        }
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This will probably help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875344/how-to-kill-the-last-opened-internet-explorer-window-using-a-command I wouldnt say its exactly a duplicate but I feel it applies.

Comment: There is no accurate way around this because there isn't any difference to how it's launched from a user vs programatically. Your solution would be to have your tests run in a VM or dedicated box which users cannot open anything on. It means any open process would be a process your test, and only your test, would have opened. That said, does killing the driver *only* kill the IE instance? I would have thought it would, but may be wrong.

Comment: How does Selenium open the web browsers? If they are opened as child processes you could handle this. However it looks from your code that they are independent.